# Stack problem java. Postfix Evaluation

Tags: java

Hey Guys I'm having a problem when I run my program. In the PostfixEvaluate() Method is where it takes in a string and solves the postfix problem and returns it. Well when I go to run it, I'm getting a bunch of random numbers(some repeated), I'm going crazy because I don't know what else to try and I've spent more time on this than it should normally take.

Heres the PostfixEvaluate Method:

```
   public int PostfixEvaluate(String e){
        //String Operator = "";
    int number1;
        int number2;
        int result=0;
        char c;
        //number1 = 0;
        //number2 = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < e.length(); j++){
            c = e.charAt(j);
            if (c != '+'&& c!= '*' && c!= '-' && c!= '/') {
                //if (c == Integer.parseInt(e)) {   
                s.push(c); 
        }
            else {
                number1 = s.pop();
                number2 = s.pop();
                switch(c) {
                    case '+':
                    result = number1 + number2;
                    break;
                    case '-':
                    result = number1 - number2;
                    break;
                    case '*':
                    result = number1 * number2;
                    break;
                    case '/':
                    result = number1 / number2;
                    break;
                    } s.push(result);
                }
            System.out.println(result);
        } 
            return s.pop();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stacked st = new Stacked(100);
    String y = new String("(z * j)/(b * 8) ^2");
    String x = new String("2 3 + 9 *");
    TestingClass clas = new TestingClass(st);

    clas.test(y);


    clas.PostfixEvaluate(x);




 }
        }
```

This is the Stack Class:

```
 public class Stacked  {

    int top;
    char stack[];
    int maxLen;

    public Stacked(int max) {
        top = -1; 
        maxLen = max; 
        stack = new char[maxLen];

        }

    public void push(int result) {
            top++;
            stack[top] = (char)result;

        }

    public int pop() {
        int x;
        x = stack[top];
        //top = top - 1;
        top--;

        return x;

    }

    public boolean isStackEmpty() {
            if(top == -1) {
                System.out.println("Stack is empty " + "Equation Good");

                return true;
            } 
            else 
                System.out.println("Equation is No good");
                return false;
    }

    public void reset() {

        top = -1;
    }

    public void showStack() {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Stack Contents...");
        for(int j = top; j > -1; j--){
            System.out.println(stack[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public void showStack0toTop() {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Stack Contents...");
        for(int j=0; j>=top; j++){
            System.out.println(stack[j]); 
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should really implement a parser first that returns tokens that are either operands (numbers) or operators (+-*/ and so on) and operate on those in your algorithm. Makes the code simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: The problem description _"I'm getting a bunch of random numbers(some repeated)"_ doesn't tell me much. Could you be more precise?

Comment: Well before I do that I changed the code at the end of postfixeval. method to pop at the end and then print the result and then return the result. Right now I'm getting 1824 as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the string into tokens first:

```
/* Splits the expression up into several Strings,
 * all of which are either a number or and operator,
 * none of which have spaces in them. */
String [] expressionAsTokens = e.split(" ");
```

Then you need to make sure you compare Strings, not chars:

```
//compare strings instead of chars
String token = expressionAsTokens[j];
if (!"+".equals(token) && !"*".equals(token) && !"-".equals(token) && !"/".equals(token)) {
    s.push(Integer.parseInt(token)); 
} else {
    //same code as you had before
}
```

Also, is there any reason you are storing everything as a `char` array in your `Stacked` class? Your `pop()` method returns and integer, yet everything is stored as a `char`.

For this application, everything should be stored as an integer:

```
public class Stacked {
    int stack[]; // array is of type integer
    int top;
    int maxLen;

    // constructor

    public void push() {/*...*/}
    public int pop() {/*...*/} //pop returns an int as before

    //...
}
```

One final note: Be careful what order you add and subtract the numbers in. I don't remember if postfix operands are evaluated left first or right first, but make sure you get them in the right order. As you have it now, `2 3 - 4 *` would evaluate as `4 * (3 - 2)` and I think it should be `(2 - 3) * 4`. This won't matter with adding and multiplying, but it will with subtracting and dividing.

Comment: Yea I tried all of this and I even made the stack int[]. Now I keep getting:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at TestingClass.PostfixEvaluate(TestingClass.java:88)
 at TestingClass.main(TestingClass.java:120)

Comment: A `NumberFormatException` means that you tried to pass `+` into the `Integer.parseInt()` method. Make sure you wrote that if statement correctly. It should be `if (!"+".equals(token) && ...`.

Comment: When I click on the TestingClass.PostfixEvaluate(TestingClass.java:88)..it points to switch(Integer.parseInt(token)

Comment: You shouldn't have that code there. Once you make it to that else statement, you will only be dealing with operators. Use strings and an if-else if statement instead: `String operator = expressionAsTokens[j]; if (operator.equals("+")) {result = ...`

Comment: I cannot catch a break lol, now its saying:    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at TestingClass.PostfixEvaluate(TestingClass.java:75)
 at TestingClass.main(TestingClass.java:132)

Comment: pointing to String token = tokens[j]; right before the for(loop)

Comment: It would help if you posted line 132. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means that you have tried to access the nth index of an array when the size of the array is n. Remember: an array of size n is indexed 0 - n-1.

Comment: In the for loop, make sure its `j < expressionAsTokens.length` not `<=`

Comment: line 132 is in the main method: clas.PostfixEvaluate(x);

Comment: Sorry, I meant 75. The line where the error is. You posted it after I started responding. :) oops

Comment: Ok I go rid of the arrayindexoutofbouunds error. I had in the for loop e.length() i changed to tokens.length, however now Im getting the wrong anwser. I'm getting 3 instead of 5. I put in the mainmethod ("2 3 +") which should be 5 not 3

Comment: Your code has changed enough that I am having troubling following, and the comment thread is perhaps the wrong venue for debugging. I suggest that every time you push or pop anything to or from the stack, throw in a `System.out.println()` describing what you did. That will make it easier to see where your error is.

Don't be discouraged. This kind of trial and error happened to everyone when we started. :) 

If you try hard and you still can't get it to work, consider posting another question. We have gone outside the scope of this one. Select the best answer and move on.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help..I'm extremely close. I have 3 2 + working but getting another arrayexception error when i try 3 2 + 3 *..I really appreciate your time and help though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you aren't handling spaces at all.

This means that when you put in a space, it is implicitly converting the character space to the ascii value of it (32) when it pops it off the stack during an operation. Also, it looks like you are assuming that all numbers/results will be single digit, and casting from char to int, which is not what you want to do, since that will convert the char to the ascii value of the char, ' ' -> 32, '3' -> 51, etc.

If I were you, I would do this for your loop in PostfixEvaluate:

```
while(!e.equals("")){
    string c;
    int space = e.indexOf(' ');
    if(space!=-1){
        c = e.substring(0,space);
        e = e.substring(space+2);
    } else{
        c = e;
        e = "";
    }
    if (!c.equals("+")&& !c.equal("*") && !c.equals("-") && !c.equals("/")) {
    //...
}
```

and change your stack to hold strings or ints.

Comment: I mean that in the main method, you are passing "2 3 + 9 *" into PostfixEvaluate. When you hit the +, the top 2 items in the stack will be a ' ' (space character) and a '3', which will convert to 32 and 51 (the ascii codes for ' ' and '3' when you cast them as integers. So I think your first result will actually be 83 (I was wrong before), since you store them as char in the stack.

Comment: Even when I store them as a int i still get the same answer

Comment: Or 57 * 32, which is '9' * ' '. You NEED to handle spaces, and casting between ints and chars will not get you what you want. You need to parse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pushing `char` onto a stack as an `int`, so you are unintentionally working with the `ascii` representations of numbers, which is not the actual value of the number.

Instead of this complicated character walking, tokenize the input string using `String.split()`. Example:

```
String[] tokens = e.split(" ");
for(String token:tokens){
    if (!"+".equals(token) && !"*".equals(token) && !"-".equals(token) && !"/".equals(token)) {
        s.push(Integer.parseInt(token)); 
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at TestingClass.PostfixEvaluate(TestingClass.java:86)
 at TestingClass.main(TestingClass.java:118)

Comment: @Tony Lagarrigue, then you've missed a `!` somewhere in your copy/paste, probably the very first one